# jQuery Keydown event makes ball disappear

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, keydown

This is my first time using jQuery's `keydown` event. I followed my lecturers instructions but the event still does not work properly. I tried everything to my knowledge.

The application executes, but every time I press an arrow key the moving ball just disappears into thin air. The arrow keys are meant to increase/decrease the velocity of the moving ball.

```js
// Gets a handle to the element with id canvasOne.
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas-for-ball");
// Get a 2D context for the canvas.
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

// The vertical location of the ball.
var y = 15;
var x = 25;
//data of ball
var ballRadius = 20;
var ySpeed = 1;
var xSpeed = 1;
var slices = 7;

class Ball {
  constructor(x, y, ballRadius, ySpeed, xSpeed, slices) {
    this._x = x;
    this._y = y
    this._ballRadius = ballRadius;
    this._ySpeed = ySpeed;
    this._xSpeed = xSpeed;
    this._slices = slices;
  } //endConstructor

  // setter for ySpeed
  set VerticleSpeed(val) {
    this._ySpeed = val;
  }

  //getter/setter for y
  get VerticlePosition() {
    return this._y;
  }

  // setter for xSpeed
  set HorizontalSpeed(val) {
    this._xSpeed = val;
  }

  //getter/setter for y
  get HorizontalPosition() {
    return this._x;
  }

  //dont need 'function' keyword infront of a function -- Note for the future
  drawball() {
    //variables for slicing beachball
    var newX = 20;
    var newY = 20;
    var i = 0;

    ctx.beginPath();
    //outer circle
    ctx.arc(this._x, this._y, this._ballRadius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    //inner circle (for beachball)
    ctx.arc(this._x, this._y, this._ballRadius * 0.85, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    //draw line from center to edge
    ctx.moveTo(this._x, this._y);
    ctx.lineTo(this._x + this._ballRadius, this._y);
    ctx.stroke();

    //loop to draw slices
    for (i = 1; i < this._slices; i++) {
      newX = this._ballRadius * Math.cos((i * 2 * Math.PI) / this._slices) + this._x;
      newY = this._ballRadius * Math.sin((i * 2 * Math.PI) / this._slices) + this._y;
      ctx.moveTo(newX, newY);
      ctx.lineTo(this._x, this._y);
      ctx.closePath();
      ctx.stroke();
    }

    //colors ball orange
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(255, 165, 0)";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();
  } //endDrawball

  draw() {
    ctx.clearRect(1, 1, 800, 800);
    this.drawball();
  } //endDraw

  move() {
    // Update the y+x location.
    this._y += this._ySpeed;
    this._x += this._xSpeed;

    //bounce if its outside the bounds x and y
    if (myBall.VerticlePosition > canvas.height) {
      myBall.VerticleSpeed = -ySpeed;
    } else if (myBall.VerticlePosition <= 0) {
      myBall.VerticleSpeed = ySpeed;
    }

    if (myBall.HorizontalPosition > canvas.width) {
      myBall.HorizontalSpeed = -xSpeed;
    } else if (myBall.HorizontalPosition <= 0) {
      myBall.HorizontalSpeed = xSpeed;
    }


    //console.log("Ball position y/x", this._y, this._x);
  }

} //endBall

// Add a Javascript event listener to the keypress event.
window.addEventListener("keypress", function(event) {
  // Just log the event to the console.
  console.log(event);
});

//keypresses with jQuery
$(document.body).on('keydown', function(e) {
  console.log(e.which);
  switch (e.which) {
    // key code for left arrow
    case 37:
      console.log('left arrow key pressed!');
      myBall.HorizontalSpeed--;
      break;
      //key code for up arrow
    case 38:
      console.log('up arrow key pressed!');
      myBall.VerticleSpeed++;
      break;
      // key code for right arrow
    case 39:
      console.log('right arrow key pressed!');
      myBall.HorizontalSpeed++;
      break;
      // key code for down arrow
    case 40:
      console.log('down arrow key pressed!');
      myBall.VerticleSpeed--;
      break;
  }
});

// A function to repeat every time the animation loops.
function repeatme() {
  // Draw the ball (stroked, not filled).
  myBall.draw();
  myBall.move();

  window.requestAnimationFrame(repeatme);
}

// create an instance of class
let myBall = new Ball(x, y, ballRadius, ySpeed, xSpeed, slices)
// Get the animation going.
repeatme();
```

```css
body {
  background-color: white;
}

canvas {
  border: 3px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas-for-ball" height="800px" width="800px"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to apply a mathematical operation directly to the modifiers get and set (**HorizontalSpeed/VerticalSpeed**);

```
myBall.HorizontalSpeed--;
```

Try updating this line to;

```
myBall._ySpeed--;
```

Or;

```
myBall.HorizontalSpeed(myBall._ySpeed--);
```